# How many different sums of k elements are in the range [1,n]?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

For example, with k = 2 and n = 4, in [1,4] there are sums 1+2=3, 1+3=4, 1+4=5 (or 2+3=5),2+4=6, and 3+4=7 Thus, the answer is 5.

Comment: what have you tried for larger values of k,n?

Comment: Hint: Figure out the smallest and largest sums, call them $m$ and $M$. By looking at more examples for various small $k$ and $n$, try to find a pattern describing which sums in the range $[m,M]$ are _not_ attainable. Then prove your pattern holds in general, and count the number of numbers fitting that pattern.

Comment: What about $3+4 (=7)$ ?

Comment: Thank you, Adam, for spotting that mistake. Edited.

Comment: The body of the Question should be used to give a complete problem statement.  Splitting the problem between title and body makes it hard to follow, so try to make the body text stand on its own.  Also merely stating a problem is not enough to ask a suitable Question.  You should put the problem in some sort of context:  where it comes from, what you tried, or what about it interests you.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, lets consider the range $[1,100]$ and $k=3$. My smalliest number would be $1+2+3 = 6$ and my largest would be $98+99+100 = 297$. Notice that I can create any number between 297 and 6 just my taking my smallest number $1+2+3=6$ and adding an integer to the $3$. So lets say I want to create the number $50$ then, $1+2+(3+44)=50$. Therefore, the total number of valid creations is $297-6+1=294$.

Now let us generalize this:

The easiest way to get the smallest sum is by simply adding the smallest numbers together:
$$1+2 +...+k = \sum_{i=1}^ki = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

The easiest way to get the largest sum is pretty much the same, but instead we want to add the largest numbers:
$$n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+(n-k+1) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)$$
Thus the total amount of possible numbers is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i -\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+1 =kn-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+1=k(n-k)+1$$

Comment: Hello :) it's only a typo, we have $1+2+3=6\neq 5$.

Comment: @Jochen Good catch. Will fix.

Comment: @Stan: Assuming the $k$ numbers are elements in $[1,n]$ we also have to consider  multiple occurrences of elements to form valid sums.

Comment: @epi163sqrt Based on the wording of the question "How many different sums of $k$ elements are in the range", I do not think we need to account for that. The sum of $2+5$ is the same as the sum of $6+1$ and so on.

Comment: @sStand: I think we should also consider in your example $k=3$ sums as $1+1+1=3$  and $100+100+100=300$ since we do not necessarily have to select *pairwise different* elements from $[1,100]$.